# Domain-wide authorisation for a Google Apps script / add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

We developed a little script/add-on for one of our Google spreadsheets. Can I as G Suite admin activate this script for all of ouf G Suite users? Or has every user to do this by himself?

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: This is well documented by Google: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide

Answer (score 0):

At the time of publishing an add-on, you can choose to keep it [Private](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-overview#private), that would make the add-ons...

> ...only visible to users in the same domain as the add-on publishing account. They can't be installed by outside users. Private add-ons do not require [add-on review](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-review). Private visibility is sometimes referred to as My Domain visibility.

Hope this information helps.